# Как сделать редирект на сокет сервере?

Tags: java

Я делаю что-то типа своего apatche и я завис на теме, как сделать редирект, что бы пользователя перебросило на указываемый url?

Заголовок Location не работатет, либо что-то нужно изменить, что-бы браузеры понимали, что нужно сделать переадресацию

[image: Заголовок Location]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно [описанию HTTP заголовка Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location):

> The Location response header indicates the URL to redirect a page to.
> It only provides a meaning when served with a 3xx (redirection) or 201
> (created) status response.

Нужно статус ответа делать 3xx (например, `307 (Temporary Redirect)`) или 201, а **у вас статус 200**